# Javascript, Flotr2 what does it mean [[ value,value]]

Tags: javascript, flotr

I'm not a javascript expert but i know how to use it. But i don't understand this code:

```
d2 = [[0, 3]]
```

What does it mean? I can't find it on google. I'm lost, i tried to change 0 by any other number but it changed nothing.

This code is part of the pie chart example on the flotr2 website:
http://humblesoftware.com/flotr2/index#!basic-pie

Comment: It's an array containing an array.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking here. It's an array of arrays used to contain data for the graph. Maybe you could be more specific?

Comment: [JavaScript For Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/755/JavaScript-For-Beginners)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its an array containing one single item in it which happens to be an array that contains two elements: 0 and 3. You can extend it to be a matrix.

```
d2 = [
        ["1,1", "1,2", "1,3"]
      , ["2,1", "2,2", "2,3"]
      , ["3,1", "3,2", "3,3"]
];

d2[0][0] === "1,1"; // The first element
```

Or maybe an array of x-y points.

```
d2 = [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]]; // points in the equation: y = x;
d3 = [[1,1], [2,4], [3,9]]; // points in the equation: y = x^2;
```

This is called an array literal. An array can contain anything, including arrays, objects etc.

[image]

Image taken from [json.org](http://json.org/)

Comment: Thank you! Maybe i'm a little stupid ^^'. i Never though it can be so simple. Then, why do they put an array with a useless value(in this case that's what it seems to be) inside an array? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell

```
d2 = [[0, 3]]
```

For the above snippet:

d2: data series 2 value
0: represents the x coordinate value (ignored in pie charts)
3: represents the y coordinate value

Since the x coordinate value is ignored, why do we need it? No idea.. probably just lazy coding.

FYI: Note that:

```
d2 = [[, 3]]
```

...renders properly too, but

```
d2 = [[3]]
```

...throws an error